# Exclude certain people (ip's) from viewing 'website under construction' page

Tags: redirect, ip-address, html

I'm working on a site, so i'd like to place a 'website under construction' page for anyone who tries to view it. The thing is, I want a selected group of people to view the real, actual, undeveloped page when they type the regarding website in their adress bar. The rest would be automatically redirected to the 'under construction' page.(is there a name for this phenomenom?)

Question summarized: Is it possible to auto-redirect people to the 'under contruction' page, but exclude certain ip's from being redirected? I only have some knowledge of HTML, CSS, PHP, and a little bit of JS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This was a solution for me, which i was satisfied with. It could be that it doesn't meet the requirements of people with the same problem.

I created a .htaccess file in my root directory.
Here I denied all ip's but the one's who should have access to it.
I then created a (temporary) custom 403(forbidden) ErrorDocument which is a
'Website under construction' page, as long as the website isn't launched.
I'll set that back to the default page when the site's ready.

My .htaccess file is now as follows:

`ErrorDocument 403 /forbidden.php
 Order deny,allow
 deny from all
 allow from 123.123.123.123`

Because it doesn't answer the specific question, i didn't mark it as best answer.